# Can I check-in online for self transfer flights?

Tags: schengen, transit, italy, ryanair, self-transfer

I want to buy a ticket through Skyscanner, but the ticket shows self transfer. It has connections in Istanbul and Rome (FCO) with two separate carriers, Pegasus and Ryanair.

The Istanbul connection is with the same carrier, but the Rome connection is not. Both flight in Rome, inbound and outbound, are in Terminal 2.

Can I check in online for all the flights, and do I need transit visas?

In Spain, I'm flying from Barcelona to Seville, Is there a way to go through Spanish immigration in Seville or do I have to clear Immigration in Barcelona?

I am Tunisian and have a single-entry Schengen visa.

Comment: Your citizenship ?

Comment: My citizenship is Tunisia which does not allow me to enter the schengen area without a visa and I have single entry visa to Spain

Comment: Is this single entry for Spain, or for Schengen countries issued by Spain? In the latter case, you clear immigration in Rome (independent of anything else) and continue to Spain "domestically" - there are a lot of questions around here discussing this very same scenario in different flavours.

Comment: Can I clear Immigration in Spain ? Because the visa is a schengen visa for single entry and I want it to be cleared in Spain

Comment: The airport I am going to in Spain is Seville from Barcelona. Is there a way to pass Spanish immigration in Seville or do I have to clear Immigration in Barcelona ?

Comment: @Lilo You clear immigration where you first enter schengen area. Flight Rome-Sevilla is a domestic flight, there is no immigration.

Comment: Why do you "want it to be cleared in Spain"?

Comment: The only way you can clear Schengen immigration in Spain is to travel directly to Spain from a non-Schengen country.

Comment: May be worthwhile to post your entire itinerary (along with carriers)  to avoid confusion.

Comment: Pegasus (Doha --> Istanbul -->  Rome) 
Ryanair (Rome --> Seville)

Comment: So where does Barcelona come into picture?

Comment: I can book another flight. But this flight is two more times the price

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are actually three questions:

1. On-line check-in. Whether you can check in online for a given flight is a matter for the carrier that issued your ticket. Check with them.
2. Istanbul transit. According to [Frequently Asked Questions / Rep. of Turkey Ministry of Foreign Affairs](http://www.mfa.gov.tr/frequently-asked-questions.en.mfa), you do not need a visa if you stay in the transit lounge. The airline for the Istanbul flights should be able to tell you if there is any need to leave the transit lounge, but that is unlikely given connecting international flights on a single ticket.
3. Schengen passport control. For most passport control purposes, the Schengen zone functions as a single country. You will use your single entry to the Schengen zone when you arrive at Rome. A flight from Rome to Barcelona is intra-Schengen, not involving a Schengen entry. Assuming, as appears to be the case, Spain is your main destination, it was correct to get the visa from Spain.